# Can I branch off my main service, just past the meter base?

Tags: electrical

Can you branch off your main electrical service line to 3 beaker panels?  1 for the house, 1 for a shed and 1 for a shop.  The house has a 200 amp breaker panel, the shed now has a sub panel powered off a 40 amp breaker from the main house panel. I want to replace the sub panel in the shed with its own breaker panel. The new shop will need an 100 amp breaker panel.  Can this be done using polaris lugs to branch off the main service line and wire to the 3 locations I need.

Comment: The experts will tell you **exactly** what to do. But short answer: 1 - Tell us what meter main you have right now - picture would help, 2 - Tell us what panels you have, pictures would help, 3 - What is your utility company? (Makes a difference sometimes in what can be installed *at the meter*). Then the basic answer is likely: can't just tie everything together unless various requirements are met but in particular protection for the wires to each panel. End result likely a small panel at/with the meter that feeds to each of your locations.

Comment: Who do you have for a utility? Can you post photos of the existing house and shed panels please?  Does your existing service come in at the house, or at a pole with the meter on it, and is it overhead or underground?

Comment: Very likely this will require a meter box upgrade. You probably have a 200A meter & box for your 200A service. If your area has adopted NEC 2020 you'll have some additional stuff required if re-working the service entrance, as you now need to provide an exterior shutoff. You may also need breakers on the shed/shop feeds to protect the lines feeding those.

Comment: As I read the 2020 code the shut off is now required at the utility connection or meter location. The NEC adoption map says 6 states on the 2020 but I only  could see 5 on the map. Local requirements may have this even if you are not on the 2020 requirements I think my state has required this for 6~ years

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

You can buy a meter disconnect all in one [like this one](https://www.homedepot.com/p/Leviton-200-Amp-8-Space-Outdoor-Load-Center-Meter-Main-with-Main-Breaker-and-Feed-Thru-Lugs-LP820-HMC/308529793).

I personally would not buy the Leviton  but this is just an example.

You just need to pull a permit and order a disconnect from the city.

Just check with your local authorities that you won't need to upgrade to a 320 amp service.

As far as 2020 code goes you'll need a sticker that says emergency disconnect since this meter has a main breaker.

Comment: Please use capitol letters to start a sentence and punctuate properly.

Comment: @AlaskaMan Added the link. Thanks for the Punctuation.

Comment: I would not make recommendations as to meter-mains until we know more about the OP's electric utility -- different utilities have different meter specs (ring vs ringless meter mounting, various bypass means), and furthermore, there are still utilities that do not permit customers to supply meter mounting equipment

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel Would this meter disconnect then become the "main" panel since it has a main breaker (i.e. it's the first panel that the supply touches)? If so, this would require de-bonding the ground/neutral in the current main panel since it would become a subpanel.  Point being, this may be more than a "just put this box in-line" type of job.

Comment: @tnknepp -- these sorts of "all in one" panels with a meter socket + disconnect or loadcenter are *always* main panels, as they have a factory bonded neutral bar in them that can't be unbonded, so yeah.